# paintComponent() not painting rectangles correctly

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent, repaint

I have a painted grid of custom rectangles inside a JPanel. I have rectangles stored in a list of rectangles. I have added a MouseMotionListener and a MouseListener to the JPanel; Both of these components will listen to either the users click or their click and hold, find out the position of where the mouse reticle is, loop through my list of rectangles and update its enum value accordingly. I then call repaint() to redraw the rectangles in the list on JPanel. The only thing is that on repainting the list, instead of just painting that one rectangle, it paints the entire column. Please Help.

[image]

**My Initialization of the initial rectangle list**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                initList.add(new PathRectangle(i*49, j*49, 49, 49));
            }
        }
        
        mainPanel = new MainPanel(10, 10, initList);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
```

**My Rectangle Class**

```
import  java.awt.*;

public class PathRectangle extends Rectangle
{

    private recType recVal = recType.UNDECLARED;

    //double pythHeurVal, manhattanHeurVal;

    public PathRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public enum recType{WALL, STARTNODE, ENDNODE, UNDECLARED}

    public recType getRecVal() {
        return this.recVal;
    }

    public void setRecVal(recType wall) {
        this.recVal = wall;
    }


}
```

**Adding Mouse Motion Listener**

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                   //System.out.println(e.getPoint());
                    for(int i = 0; i < paintedRectangles.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if(paintedRectangles.get(i).contains(e.getPoint()))
                        {
                            //This will have to change in the future just testing it right now
                            paintedRectangles.get(i).setRecVal(PathRectangle.recType.WALL);
                            
                            
                            repaint();
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
```

**Adding MouseListener**

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
           
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                
                for(int i = 0; i < paintedRectangles.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if(paintedRectangles.get(i).contains(e.getPoint()))
                        {
                            //This will have to change in the future just testing it right now
                            paintedRectangles.get(i).setRecVal(PathRectangle.recType.WALL);
                            
                            
                            repaint();
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
```

**paintComponent method**

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                
                switch(paintedRectangles.get(i).getRecVal())
                {
                    case UNDECLARED:
                    g2D.drawRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                    break;

                    case WALL:
                    g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2D.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j * rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                    break;

                    case STARTNODE:
                    g2D.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g2D.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                    break;

                    case ENDNODE:
                    g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2D.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If overwriting `paintComponent()` you should call `super.paintComponent()` First to clear everything painted previously.

Comment: You edited your post to include the suggestion made by @weisj, does that mean that worked or that didn't work?

Comment: @yur No, it was a minor mistake that I had just forgotten to put in.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: (1-) 1) Why have you deleted your last question on this topic? It was already suggested that the painting of rectangles should be done based on the rectangles in your "paintedRectangles" list, instead of recalculating the rectangle in the paintComponent() method. This will ensure that hit detection and painting are consistent. 2) What debugging have you done yourself? I don't see any debug code that will verify if your enum values are correct or if the painting is correct.

Comment: @camickr I deleted the last post because I wasn't getting any answers and my issue had changed so much that I thought It would be weird if had edited the question. What do you mean painting based on the "paintedRectangles" list, don't I already do that: looping though the list to find out the distinct properties of each rectangle? I have tried a variety of thing including checking the bounds of the rectangle with getpoint(). Thank you

Comment: *I wasn't getting any answers*  1) you got a suggestion to improve the painting to reduce the possibilities of painting errors, yet you ignored the suggestion.2) you got suggestion on how to do basic debugging which still applies here. *What do you mean painting based on the "paintedRectangles"* - The `PaintedRectangle` object in the ArrayList already contains the bounds of the Rectangle. Why does the paintComponent () method recalculate the bounds using i, j, rectLenWidSize. This is how you introduce inconsistencies when you do hit detection using the Rectangle but paint using something else.

Comment: Did you add debug code in the paint method when you check for the "wall". Did you display the i, j values. Or maybe is the problem the code invokes the "undeclared" painting and the default color is BLACK. You have NOT posted an MRE so we are not able to test your code. So you need to do basic debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like this you are going to need two-dimensional ArrayLists. One-dimensional ArrayLists don't represent the Grid correctly.

I also noticed I made a couple mistakes when making the first initialization ArrayList

**My Initialization of the initialization of the rectangle list**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ArrayList<PathRectangle> initColList = new ArrayList<PathRectangle>();

            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                initColList.add(new PathRectangle(i*49, j*49, 49, 49));
            }

            initList.add(initColList);
        }
```

**paintComponent method**

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    for(int i = 0; i < paintedRectangles.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < paintedRectangles.get(0).size(); j++)
        {
            
            //System.out.println(paintedRectangles.get(i).get(j).getRecVal());
            switch(paintedRectangles.get(i).get(j).getRecVal())
            {
                case UNDECLARED:
                g2D.drawRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                break;

                case WALL:
                g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2D.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j * rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                break;

                case STARTNODE:
                g2D.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2D.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                break;

                case ENDNODE:
                g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2D.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```